# Is the question answered?

Tags: discussion

In one of my questions ( [Get list of operators in a menu layout](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13519/get-list-of-operators-in-a-menu-layout) ) the answer offered is "so far, you can't, here is a workaround" which is not a very safe option... Should I mark the question as answered or wait for a better (in a future version?) answer, and leave the question open ?

What is the rule in this kind of cases ?

Comment: Now you have decide whether or not to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 3):

From the Help Center :

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but **not every user comes back to accept an answer**, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.